# Why my scrollbar is missing by using scrollArea on PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to put some articles on my scrollArea, so I build it on the QtDesigner, but when I executed my codes, I couldn't see my scrollbar.  I've tried other solutions, but it didn't work.

I don't know what I miss, and I feel confused on how do I modify my code.

[image: QtDesigner]

```
class Ui_NewsWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, NewsWidget):
        NewsWidget.setObjectName("NewsWidget")
        NewsWidget.resize(802, 600)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(NewsWidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 761, 481))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.news_listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.news_listWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 16777215))
        self.news_listWidget.setObjectName("news_listWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.news_listWidget)
        
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 501, 477))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 501, 481))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.news_txtheading = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.news_txtheading.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.news_txtheading.setFont(font)
        self.news_txtheading.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.news_txtheading.setObjectName("news_txtheading")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.news_txtheading)

        self.news_txtcontent = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.news_txtcontent.setFont(font)
        self.news_txtcontent.setWordWrap(True) 
        self.news_txtcontent.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.news_txtcontent.setObjectName("news_txtcontent")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.news_txtcontent)
        
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.retranslateUi(NewsWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(NewsWidget)
```

Comment: You're missing a proper layout on the top level widget and in the `scrollAreaWidgetContents`. If you look at those icons, you'll see that small red circled alert. Right click on "NewsWidget" and select `Lay out vertically" from the `Lay out` submenu, then move those 4 labels outside that vertical layout, remove it, and do the same as above by right clicking on "scrollAreaWidgetContents". You can do the same by right clicking on an empty area of the *parent* widget you want to set the layout for. Also ensure that the property "widgetResizable" of the scroll area is checked.

Comment: I breaked  the vertically layout, but I still can't see my scrollbar and the content in my label is cutted down.

Comment: That's because you probably just broke the layout and didn't set a proper one. If you still see that red circle warning on any parent widget, that's the reason. If you still don't get it I suggest you to [edit] your post, remove the python code and add the original UI file instead.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I can see my scrollbar, but why some words of the  label is still cutted down on the bottom of the scrollArea?

Comment: As said, the code you provided doesn't completely match the object structure of the image, so you must provide the UI file if you want further help.